# Draw a polyline that follows moving marker in Leaflet

Tags: javascript, html, css, leaflet

I have one question I'm using Leaflet and having GPS Coordinates every 2 seconds, relating to moving objects on the map, I sucessfully created a moving marker based on gps coordinates every 2 seconds, but then I failed to draw a polyline that follows the marker.

Do you have any idea ? Thanks

```
     var redraw = function(p3DMessage){

            lat = parseFloat(p3DMessage.lat);
            lng = parseFloat(p3DMessage.lon);
            console.log(lat)
            console.log(lng)


            if (theMarker != undefined) {
                  mymap.removeLayer(theMarker);
            };


            var polylinePoints = [[lat, lng]];

            //failed to draw polyline...
            //L.polyline([[lat, lng]]).addTo(mymap);      

            theMarker = L.marker([lat,lng]).addTo(mymap);  
        };
```

Answer (score 13, accepted):

[`Polyline.addLatLng`](http://leafletjs.com/reference-1.2.0.html#polyline-addlatlng) lets you add a point to an existing polyline.

So build your map, add a polyline and add a point at each tick of your drawing function. Note that you can also reuse your marker. Something like

```
var map = L.map(document.getElementById('map')).setView([48.8583736, 2.2922926], 15);

L.tileLayer('http://{s}.tile.osm.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png', {
    attribution: '&copy; <a href="http://osm.org/copyright">OpenStreetMap</a> contributors'
}).addTo(map);

var marker = null;
var line = L.polyline([]).addTo(map);

function redraw (p3DMessage) {
    var lat = parseFloat(p3DMessage.lat),
        lng = parseFloat(p3DMessage.lon),
        point = {lat: lat, lng: lng};

    if (!marker) {
        marker = L.marker(point).addTo(map)
    }

    line.addLatLng(point);
    marker.setLatLng(point);
}
```

And a demo

```js
var map = L.map(document.getElementById('map')).setView([48.8583736, 2.2922926], 15);

    L.tileLayer('http://{s}.tile.osm.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png', {
        attribution: '&copy; <a href="http://osm.org/copyright">OpenStreetMap</a> contributors'
    }).addTo(map);

    var points = [
        {lat: 48.857, lon:2.2922926},
        {lat: 48.858, lon:2.291},
        {lat: 48.859, lon:2.293},
        {lat: 48.860, lon:2.294},
        {lat: 48.862, lon:2.294},
    ];

    var marker = null;
    var line = L.polyline([]).addTo(map);

    function redraw(point) {
        if (!marker) {
            marker = L.marker(point).addTo(map)
        }
        line.addLatLng(point);
        marker.setLatLng(point);
    }

    function update() {
        if (points.length) {
            redraw(points.shift());
            setTimeout(update, 1000);
        }
    }
    setTimeout(update, 1000);
```

```css
html, body {
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
}
#map {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://unpkg.com/leaflet@1.2.0/dist/leaflet.css" integrity="sha512-M2wvCLH6DSRazYeZRIm1JnYyh22purTM+FDB5CsyxtQJYeKq83arPe5wgbNmcFXGqiSH2XR8dT/fJISVA1r/zQ==" crossorigin=""/>
    <script src="https://unpkg.com/leaflet@1.2.0/dist/leaflet.js" integrity="sha512-lInM/apFSqyy1o6s89K4iQUKg6ppXEgsVxT35HbzUupEVRh2Eu9Wdl4tHj7dZO0s1uvplcYGmt3498TtHq+log==" crossorigin=""></script>
    
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/leaflet.draw/0.4.12/leaflet.draw.css" />
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/leaflet.draw/0.4.12/leaflet.draw.js"></script>

<div id='map'></div>
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help, I got the idea now, however I just have one question, as I don't have the departure coordinates (in your example is p0), when the program starts I get the very first coordinates, and from that I draw the line. So i have to reinitialize marker and polyline in redraw function ?  Thanks in advanced

Comment: @bluewonder You can start with an empty polyline and a null marker. I've modified my answer to show a possible implementation.

Comment: Merci beaucoup pour ton aide. I will take a look and change my code.